# When user remove app - delete user from my sql database

Tags: facebook

When an user remove my app from Facebook interface, I want to delete this user from my mysql database. How is possible to do that? (functions or method)

I see something at App Settings->Deauthorize Callback, when user remove app, Facebook server will send data to this page and should make a script that automatically remove that uid from my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 100% correct - your Deauthorize Callback URL will be sent a `signed_request` that you can decode to retrieve the information you need on the user that removed your application.

Comment: Here's the documentation :
"App Deauthorization

When a user of your app removes it in the App Dashboard or blocks the app in the News Feed, your app can be notified by specifying a Deauthorize Callback URL in the Developer App. During app removal we will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter, signed_request, which contains the user id (UID) of the user that just removed your app. You will not receive an user access token in this request and all existing user access tokens will be automatically expired."
[link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)